# Как сделать заштрихованную область qml?

Tags: c++, qt5, qml

У меня есть полигон мапы, в котором передаются координаты, но мне нужно не просто сделать обводку линиями по координатам, но также и сделать заштрихованную область.
Код полигона:

```
MapPolygon {
        id: m_mapPolygon

        property var valueOpacity: model.opacity / 100

        z: (model.valid ? model.layout : (zoneView.count + 1)) + 10
        smooth: true
        path: model.path
        visible: {
            if (MenuManager.onscreen
                    && MenuManager.currentMenuTitle === qsTr("zones"))
                return true

            if(model.species === Species.Polygon)
                return model.visible

            return false
        }
        enabled: MenuManager.currentMenuTitle === qsTr("zones")
        border {
            // Задаём цвет границы зоны
            color: model.valid ? model.color : "red"
            // Задаём ширину границы зоны
            width: model.lineWidth
        }
        color: {
            const c = border.color
            // Если выбрана зона (полигон), то делаем темнее, иначе наоборот светлее.
            // Коэффициент затемнения alpha = 0.5
            return Qt.rgba(c.r, c.g, c.b, model.locked ? m_mapPolygon.valueOpacity
                                                       : 0.5)
        }
    }
```

Я нагуглил такое понятние как OpacityMask и там возможно наложение полигонов, но как мне сделать именно заштрихованную область как на картинке? [image: Картинка]

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/63664/how-to-draw-a-polygon-with-qml/8

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, не понимаю зачем мне то, что просто рисует полигон. То что вы скинули - это объяснение отрисовки полигона средствами канваса...